# weird error when connecting in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

i am getting a weird error when i connect my outlets in my xib.

I have a tab bar app, with 3 tabs. the first two work perfectly, but the third tab is having problems - it crashes the app when you push it when any IBOutlets are connected in IB. if you remove the connections, but leave them declared in xcode then it works fine. but as soon as i connect them again, it crashes the app.

any thoughts?

********** added code *********

.h

```
@interface Orders : UIViewController {

    UILabel *username, *customer; 
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UILabel *username, *customer;
```

.m

> @implementation Orders @synthesize
>   username, customer;

message from console

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for
>   the key username.'

[image]

Comment: will you please put screen shot?

Comment: Put screenshots for the IB connection screen for which you are getting crash. Also the screenshot of the .h file in which the related IBOutlets are declared.

Comment: have added code and error message above

Comment: I thought that too, i have changed 'readonly' to 'retain' - and still no joy

Comment: What is the file's owner type set to? Orders or UIViewController?

Comment: files owner is set to Orders...

Comment: tried that - doesnt solve it. I have just opened a new project to try and replicate the problem. and i do get the same problem. maybe it has something to do with the 3rd tab i created. the first 2 work fine, but they are supplied as it is a tab bar app. the third tab i created myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code shows the UILabels are called `customer` and `username` but the screenshot shows them called `customerLabel` and `usernameLabel` in the nib file. Make sure that you're using the same names for the views everywhere (I recommend appending "Label" to the end of the names if they are UILabels. Better to have descriptive names.).

And like Kirby says in a comment to your question, make sure that the File's Owner in the nib file is set to be an instance of your UIViewController subclass (looks like it's called "Orders" but it should really be something like "OrdersViewController").

Comment: yea, its because i was playing around with it at the time. i made sure everything matched and was easier to track - but still no joy. i started a new project now as a view based app instead and seems to be doing the job so far

Comment: Good luck! Be sure to read up in the iOS Programming Guide if you can, and play with the sample code. It takes time to become familiar with the ins and outs of views, view controllers, and nib files.